# Finds the number of items above the average of all items --- logic error cannot find it

Tags: java

I have no idea what went wrong, but I keep getting the wrong result, which is the value of the count is not correct.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Learn 
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of items: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        
        
        double[] numbers = new double[n];
        double sum = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Enter all the numbers");
        
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
            sum += numbers[i];                      
        }       
        
        double average = sum/n; 
        
        int count = 0;
        
        for(int i =0; i <n; i++)
        {   
            if(numbers[i]>average);
            count++;
        }   

        System.out.println("Average is " + average);
          
        System.out.println("Number of elements above the average is " + count);
        
    }
}
```

But with this program, it looks exactly the same as the above one, it will work correctly.
I really think these two programs are identical but why there is a different result here.

```
          java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter the number of items");
          
          int n = input.nextInt();
          double[] numbers = new double[n];
          double sum = 0;
          
          System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
          for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
          {
              numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
              sum += numbers[i];
          }
          
          double average = sum/n;
          
          int count = 0;
          
          for(int i =0; i <n;i++)
             {
                if(numbers[i] > average)              
                count++;
                
             }
          
          System.out.println("Average is " + average);
          
          System.out.println("Number of elements above the average is " + count);
```

Comment: In the first program, there is a ; after the `if(numbers[i] > average)`

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to this line:

```
for(int i =0; i <n; i++)
    {   
        **if(numbers[i]>average);**
        count++;
    }
```

you must remove the `;` from the end of the if command to increase the count if the condition is true.

If you dont change it, the code increase the count anyway, even if `numbers[i]<=average`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing this out!!!